# How to create a for loop that will initialise objects of my class instead of doing it one by one

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pygame

```
def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((675, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background.fill((0, 0, 0))

    allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    for j in range(0, 5):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            invader1 = Invader1(screen, (0, 0))
            invader1.x += 75
            invader1.add(allSprites)
        invader1.y += 75
```

I am trying to create a space invaders game for a project but im having a bit of trouble with the for loops, i want to create 10 instances of an enemy without having to type out each one, i know a for loop is the answer, im just not sure how to initialise it. I would like to start the first enemy at (0, 0) and move each enemy 75 spaces on the x axis and after 10 enemies are created move down 75 spaces on the y axis and repeat the process. Does anyone know how i would achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: for x in range(0, 10):?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to look like this:

```
def main():
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((675, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((0, 0, 0))

allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

for j in range(0, 5):
    for i in range(0, 10):
        invader1 = Invader1(screen, (75*i,75*j ))
        invader1.add(allSprites)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use ranges with a `step` parameter.

```
In [4]: range(0, 75 * 5, 75)
Out[4]: [0, 75, 150, 225, 300]
```

```
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for y in range(0, 75 * 5, 75):
    for x in range(0, 75 * 10, 75):
        Invader1(screen, (x, y)).add(allSprites)
```

Comment: They are being added to the `sprite.Group()` , so you wouldn't need a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Pavel's answer all in one line if you use a nested list comprehension

```
invaders =  [ Invader1(screen, (x, y)) for x in range(0, 750, 75) for y in range(0, 325, 75) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
invader_list = []
for y in range(n):
    for x in range(10):
        invader_list.append(Invader(x * w, y * h))
```

1) Create a list to store the objects

2) Make a for loop iterating n times (the number of rows)

3) Make a nested for loop iterating 10 times (the number of colums)

4) Inside the two for loops, make the Invader object with x*w and y*h